# Самовызывающаяся анонимная функция внутри объекта

Tags: javascript

Запутался. Пытаюсь создать объект, который должен инициализировать сам себя. Увы, в моих знаниях есть пробелы.

```
var obj = {
    //  params, functions...
    init : (function(){
          alert(obj);  
    })()    
}
```

Увы, выводится undefined, т.е. объект еще не создан, а функция уже вызвана. Каким образом решить данную проблему? Можно так:

```
...
    init  : function(){ alert(obj);}
}
```

И вызывать искусственно :

```
obj.init()
```

Однако, хотелось бы автоматизировать процесс...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Модель вычисления присваивания lvalue = rvalue такая: сначала выполняется rvalue и только потом результат присваивается lvalue. То есть ссылать из правого выражения на левое не имеет смысла, так как ему еще ничего не присвоено и оно undefined.

В правом выражение получить ссылку из недостроенного объекта на самого нельзя, поэтому ваша задумка не выйдет. К тому же не понятно, зачем и где это вообще может пригодиться?

Но можно делать следующее:

1 - вызывать функцию после построения объекта

```
var obj = ({ init:function(param2){
            this.a=10;
            this.b=param2; 
            return this;
              }
      }).init(20)
```

2 - вместо объекта создать функцию возвращающую объект

```
var obj = (function(param2){
        return { a:10, b:param2 };
      })(20);
```

3 - для автоматизации лучше изучить ООП и пользоваться им

```
function Obj(param1, param2){
    this.a=param1;
    this.b=param2;
}
a = new Obj(1,2);
b = new Obj2(10,20);
```

Comment: @Alexey123, первый ваш ответ меня устраивает. 

2й - ?

3й - ООП изучен, таким шаблоном я и пользовался до этого, однако в данный момент захотел создать объект через литерал. 

Зачем и где может пригодиться? У меня объект создает элемент div и хотелось бы, чтобы этот див без вызова дополнительных методов добавлялся к DOM.)))

Comment: Просто с моего виденья вопроса создается объект, который ничем не отличается, как если бы его создали через обычный литерал. То есть в итоге во всех трех случаях получается объект {a:10, b:20}, который можно было бы так и создать прямым прописыванием свойств, без придумывания дополнительных сложностей. Поэтому у меня и возникает вопрос в целесообразности, где это может действительно помочь. Ну кроме третьего варианта, там создание нескольких объектов на основе шаблона.

Comment: @Alexey123, ну, просто я никогда не использовал внутреннюю инициализацию объекта, поэтому и был удивлен, что вызванная функция внутри объекта еще "не знает" про его свойства, даже если они объявляются ДО самовызывающейся функции. 2й ваш вариант тоже у меня был на уме, но я задал вопрос, чтобы уточнить для себя данное поведение. В моем случае объект создает невидимый div, который должен сам поместить себя в дерево документа и ждать вызова остальных методов и свойств. Вот и все.